# rails s : undefined method `symbolize_keys'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails 3.2.12 app, but when I ran `rails s`, I got the following error : `connection_specification.rb:45:in 'resolve_hash_connection': undefined method 'symbolize_keys' for #<String:0x00000006c16b40> (NoMethodError)`

the connection_specification.rb concerned method :

```
def resolve_hash_connection(spec) # :nodoc:
  spec = spec.symbolize_keys # Line 45

  raise(AdapterNotSpecified, "database configuration does not specify adapter") unless spec.key?(:adapter)

  begin
    require "active_record/connection_adapters/#{spec[:adapter]}_adapter"
  rescue LoadError => e
    raise LoadError, "Please install the #{spec[:adapter]} adapter: `gem install activerecord-#{spec[:adapter]}-adapter` (#{e.message})", e.backtrace
  end

  adapter_method = "#{spec[:adapter]}_connection"

  ConnectionSpecification.new(spec, adapter_method)
end
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo in a file not shown.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`#symbolize_keys` is a method that takes a `Hash` as a receiver, but you're calling it on a `String`.

Comment: Can I convert this string into a hash ?

Comment: Problem solved : A space was missing in my database.yml